# Splitting [bcp] into [sql-server-bcp] and [sybase-bcp]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

So one of the legacies of SQL Server originating with Sybase is that some of the utilities between the products have the same name/purpose but significantly different syntax.

It would make much more sense for the existing tag to be split into two new tags, one for each Software Company so they can be looked after by their respective communities more easily.  As a Sybase expert, I follow the [bcp] tab, but 90%+ of the time the questions are for Microsoft, and I'm not much help.

Comment: I would almost suggest to have for bcp a similar solution as for sql: Show a warning if the naked tag is used and suggest to add a vendor tag

Comment: @rene sql is much more generic and can cover a lot of different sub-areas.  from my perspective, bcp is much more specific, as it's referring to a specific utility and it must fall into one of the two categories.